# Gradient Stroke on UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I've found the [GradientButton](http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/) class for gradients on a UIButton - however I can't figure out how to get a matching stroke around the button. How do you create a gradient stroke on the button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CALayer for this:

```
[[button layer] setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[[button layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
[[button layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```

And dont forget to import:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial of making tutorial with Core Animation by Matt Long
http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/